# помогите правильно написать запрос redbeanphp

Tags: php, redbeanphp

```
     $products = \R::findAll('product','ORDER BY rate DESC','hotdeal = 1');
```

как синтаксически правильно написать, чтобы запрос отработал?
Текст ошибки: Expected array, string given.

Comment: попробуйте так $products = \R::findAll('product','ORDER BY rate DESC',['hotdeal = 1']);

Comment: @Fabio Mendes Soares, Cпасибо! Вы помогли.

Answer (score 0):

```
$products = R::findAll('product', 'hotdeal= ? ORDER BY rate DESC', [1]);

$products = R::findAll('product', 'hotdeal= ? AND rate >= ? AND name LIKE ? ORDER BY rate DESC', [1, 50, '%Телефон%']);

$products = R::findLike('product', ['hotdeal' => [1,2,3], 'rate' => '100' ]);
```

может поможет :)

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: https://redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/finding тут подробно описано все :)